# Google analytics _trackSocial not working

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have correctly included the GA tracking code snippet found here (http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080&rd=1) and it is working (& has been for years)

I have recently set up the Facebook Javascript SDK for running code when the 'like' button is clicked - this also works.
In the same FB.Event function, I included googles _gaq.push _trackSocial as follows...

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    // do some stuff, this is working.

    // google track likes - this isn't working
    _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like']);
}
);
```

No errors in console.

So either analytics takes a long time to register the likes & I haven't waited long enough or something is wrong.

Since the FB.Event & my JS functions ARE WORKING & _gaq.push does not give any errors - I am unsure what the problem is.

In Google Analytics *Traffic Source > Social > Social Plugins*  then click on the 'Social Source' tab & it shows only Google.

Comment: FYI: Install the Chrome browser and the [GA debugger plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). You can then see if the tracker is sent in the console in real time. Later it will show up in the reports.

Answer (score 0):

24 hours later the answer is evidently that Analytics takes a long time to update.

Although I have not changed anything Analytics is now showing Facebook as a Social Plugin.

So it just takes a really long time to show up in analytics.

Comment: You can change the date range to include the current date and you won't have to wait 24 hours. By default it doesn't include 'today'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 'newer' `analytics.js` vs the legacy `ga.js` version you need to use `ga('send'...)` instead of `_gat.push(...)`.

I would have expected you to get an error in your situation, but this may help others.

[ga or _gaq.push for Google Analytics event tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696998/ga-or-gaq-push-for-google-analytics-event-tracking)

If you're trying for instance to use the [`social-tracking.js`](https://github.com/samscholfield/StuffedWeb/blob/master/social-button-tracking/social-tracking.js) from StuffedWeb alongside analytics.js then you'll need to convert it to the new call style.