# ga or _gaq.push for Google Analytics event tracking?

Tags: jquery, events, google-analytics, tracking

I would like to track an `onclick` of a button on a page on a site, after a condition is passed checking if a cookie is present.

Very simple but which syntax would work best?

I have researched the `ga` and `gaq_push` prefix of the GA event tracking syntax and (forgive me if I'm wrong) but they seem pretty similar?

**`_gaq.push`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery.cookie('entry_winagrand_cookie') !== null) {
        jQuery('notregisterbtn').on('click', function () {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'QR_Win_A_Grand', 'Clicked through to Register']);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**`ga`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     if (jQuery.cookie('entry_winagrand_cookie') !== null) {
         jQuery('notregisterbtn').on('click', function () {
             ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'QR_Win_A_Grand', 'Clicked_through_to_register');
         });
     }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you use [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) ("traditional" asynchronous code) you have to use _gaq.push. If you use [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) you need to use ga send. The methods are not interchangeable, they belong  to two different versions of the Google Analytics tracking code.

By now (2017) there is a new code version (gtag.js), so if you are using that you use neither `ga` nor `_gaq.push` but instead follow [the migration guidelines](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration#track_events) to bring your code up to the latest version (or you quite sensibly start to use Google Tag Manager).

Comment: Thanks! Too bad this was not clearly mentioned anywhere. I was wondering why there was no event tracking happening for hours!

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in the documentation. Now at least

Comment: @Martin, to be fair, that question and answer is two years old :-)

Answer (score 21):

I would create a function if you need to track different events, that way your code will be cleaner.

[analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

[ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

```
function TrackEventGA(Category, Action, Label, Value) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof (_gaq) !== "undefined") {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', Category, Action, Label, Value]);
    } else if (typeof (ga) !== "undefined") {
        ga('send', 'event', Category, Action, Label, Value);
    }
}
TrackEventGA('QR_Win_A_Grand', 'Clicked_through_to_register');
```

Answer (score 17):

If you had both analytics.js and ga.js running on your site, which is recommended while analytics.js is still in beta, you can run both, although I would combine them in the notregisterbtn function, like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (jQuery.cookie('entry_winagrand_cookie') !== null) {
            jQuery('notregisterbtn').on('click', function () {
                //you should first check if ga is set
                if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'QR_Win_A_Grand', 'Clicked_through_to_register');
                 }
                //check if _gaq is set too
                if (typeof _gaq !== 'undefined') {
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'QR_Win_A_Grand', 'Clicked through to Register']);
                }
             });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @lulalala you're correct. I made the mistake of copying and pasting OP's code. I've updated my code.

Comment: Yes for me I am noticing issues with the new preferred way ! So the new way ga('send'... isnt working though I see the network request go just fine ...
We seem to need to provide both but I am concerned that stats may not be accurate when google fix their code if it is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is my script I've got on Google Analytics page

```
 <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-77777777-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

To track my other pages in Backbone.js, I put this code in each Backbone.js View script:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', myUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* universal event tracking */
function trackEventTag(category, action, opt_label) {
    /* analytics.js send event */
    ga('send', 'event', { 'eventCategory': category, 'eventAction': action, 'eventLabel': opt_label });
    /* add delay or additional tracking here */
    return true;
}
/* send ga.js _gaq.push() events to universal tracker */
var _gaq = window._gaq || {
    push: function (ar) {
        if (ar && ar.constructor === Array && 0 in ar) {
            if (ar[0] == '_trackEvent') {
                var category = 1 in ar ? ar[1] : null, action = 2 in ar ? ar[2] : null, opt_label = 3 in ar ? ar[3] : null;
                return trackEventTag(category, action, opt_label);
            }
            /* test for others you want to translate here */
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: please add some more information and not only code. thanks!