# Google Analytics _trackEvent not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

I am trying to track each menu on the website using `_trackEvent` of Google analytic. So far Analytic is working fine but Event Tracking is not working.

Below is the code i am using

```
// Analytics
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-481xxxxx-1', 'ABC.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

and in html code i am using is like this.

```
<li>
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Top_Menu', 'contact-details']);" href="en/10/contact-details">CONTACT</a>
</li>
```

For some reason it is not tracking my events.

Am i using wrong version of analytic.

**UPDATE**: Even this is not working

```
<li> 
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', { 'eventCategory': 'Navigation', 'eventAction': 'Click', 'eventLabel': 'about-the-group});" href="en/about/about-us">ABOUT US</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You are mixing Universal Analytics (new) and asychnronous analytics (old). There is no _gaq array (and hence no _gaq.push) in Universal Analytics. See here for more info:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696998/ga-or-gaq-push-for-google-analytics-event-tracking

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I had my doubts regarding same... for the same reason i had mentioned `Am i using wrong version of analytic.` I would appreciate if you can show me an example how should i call `ga()` from an as a simple function `onClick="ga(...)"`

Comment: ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value, non-interaction); ( where value is an (optional) integer and non-interaction an (optional) boolean).

Comment: Is this okay `<a href="#" onClick=\"ga('send', 'event', {  'eventCategory': 'Navigation',  'eventAction': 'Action',  'eventLabel': '" + SEOName + "});\"> Menu </a>`  if this is right then it is still not tracking event for some reason.

Comment: Lose the Backslashes, they will cause javascript errors. And if you pass a javascript variable (SEOName) you don't need to bother with quotation marks. Otherwise that looks okay.

Comment: I am not able to make it work this is my final html rendered as outpu `<li> <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', { 'eventCategory': 'Navigation', 'eventAction': 'Click', 'eventLabel': 'about-the-group});" href="en/about/7/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

Check under the real-time reports is it showing up there.  Remember that it can take up to 24 hours for the data to show up in the standard reports.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'test', 4);"> Test Event</a>
```

This page should help you understand how it should look [Event Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Add a comment if this doesn't help.  See if i can help you get it working how you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recording the event because you are sending them to another page before the event tracking in Google Analytics has a chance to record.

See [Track outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)

This will show you how to set up a function that allows the event tracking to be sent to GA before the user is sent to another page.

Comment: I used this example also previously but for some reason it doesn't track it properly. I was able to record only one event. I stopped tracking as it also created problem for some other scripts on my page for some reason. I will try to fix the and try again.

Answer (score -1):

There's two possible reasons why this might not work:
(1) Code has a bug in it, or
(2) Its not actually sending to GA
(3) Goals not set up

I can't see anything wrong with it, so I'm going to skip over number 1.

You may want to get a GA debugger and work from there to see what is happening. If you have an analytics blocker, I recommend turning it off. Also, the data won't appear immediately. Google has the little habit of filtering data before it is presented to you.

For your goals, make sure you are actually capturing the information. I've made this mistake before. I set up the event tracking, wait for the events... and they never come. You'll have to set up a goal in GA to listen for this.

Comment: Thanks.. May be it is because of Goal as i have not set up goal.  Almost similar thing is working on other website without setting up goals. Let me try & use debugger also to further troubleshoot it.

Comment: On the other side i don't understand why i need goals as i just want to track Manu Navigation using events.. for goals i need to setup at least to pages. It is more suitable for tracking Registration process. Shopping carts etc...

Comment: (1) because the code doesn't work because hes mixing classic analytics and universal analytics.(2) You are correct here its not sending it. Because he using using Universal analytics (analytics.js) and trying to send with the ga.js code(.push). (3) Goals have nothing to do with event tracking.