# Google Analytics - tracking download clicks

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I have a website with a download button which will let you download your self-generated image (which has a generate button too). I want to track the download clicks. Here's my download button code:

```
<input class="form-row form-box blue-bg" type="button" id="download" value="Download Screensaver" disabled />
```

I've managed to track the page views with the Google Analytics standard code but I don't know how to put event tracking and somebody told me to also use Google Tag Manager which is not really familiar to me. Here's my GA code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I'm wondering if what do I need to add to the js code and the download button too, if ever. Hope someone will help me, will really appreciate this as I am new to back-end stuff and I have no superior to guide me. Thanks!

Comment: *new to back-end stuff* this is frontend stuff really

Comment: If you're confused by code, Google Tag Manager really is the way forwards; it deals with all of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the following on click of button:

Can add that in our javascript.
eg:

```
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener("click", function () {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'Download Screen Saver', 'self generated image');
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#event_fields

Please make sure above code is after the GA script you have provided in your question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for counting your downloads

```
function trackDownload(link) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Click', 'Setup executable']);
    _gaq.push(function() { document.location = link.href });
    return false;
}
<a href="files/setup.exe" onclick="return trackDownload(this);">Download</a>
```

Comment: this is for the [older version of GA and is technically out of date now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18701605/542251).